# Script in ubuntu to take CPU temperature and CPU usage in the same time and save to file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command, line

I need to write script or command line code in Ubuntu which take CPU temperature and % of CPU usage from lm_sensors or something similar and this information I would like to save in .txt file with date and time of each measurement. I tried to write .sh file which is below, temperature works but CPU usage doesn't work correctly it only save first measurement everytime. 
Can somebody help me?

```
while true;
do
  echo $( date '+%H:%M:%S' ): $( sensors | grep 'CPU Temperature' | sed -r 's/^.*:        +(.*)  +[(].*$/\1/' ) >> temperature.txt;
  echo $( date '+%H:%M:%S' ): $( top -b -n 1 | grep 'CPU:') >> cpu.txt;
  sleep 1; 
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it only save first measurement everytime"?

Comment: I mean that in cpu.txt file it saves every second the same % number of cpu usage.

Comment: Why is that an error? Do you know for a fact that it changes?

Comment: It's error for me because I have open psensor window at the same time and I see that this values are changing.

Comment: The question is clear enough to have an accepted answer, so it should be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the CPU usage as such, but only over time. The cpu usage isn't stored in a file, you have to calculate it yourself:

```
cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | awk -v RS="" '{print ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5) "%"}'
```

If you have a cpu temperature sensor, it's located in `/sys/class/hwmon`. You need to figure out yourself which one is correct, since that's driver dependent. Mine is "coretemp", I guess.

```
$ cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/name
acpitz
dell_smm
coretemp
nouveau
```

Once you found out the above, you can do the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

LOG=cpu.log
while true; do
    percentage=$(cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | awk -v RS="" '{print ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5) "%"}')
    echo -n "$(date "+%F-%T") " >> ${LOG}
    echo -n "$percentage " >> ${LOG}
    cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/temp1_input >> ${LOG}
done
exit 0
``

[1] [Getting cpu usage same every time.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69185/getting-cpu-usage-same-every-time)
```

Comment: This is how I get my CPU temperature: `sensors -j | jq --raw-output '."coretemp-isa-0000"."Core 0" | to_entries | .[] | select(.key | match("input")) | .value'` gives the result in Celcius rather than the raw value

Comment: Afaik, `temp1_input` is not a raw value but the temperature in Celsius * 1000. It's chip dependent how accurate it is, but dividing it by 1000 seems OK by me. I think it's a safe bet to say that sensors also uses the output of a file in hwmon, since sysfs (etc) is the interface to the kernel :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it on thursday if it works as I wanted to and I will let you know. :)

Comment: It works, thank you very very much!